# How do I query tables located in different database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My original question was about whether to keep separate ASPNETDB.MDF from the application database or merge all the tables in one database. Checking the previous questions/answers, I learned that it depends on whether the membership data would be shared across several applications.

Now, my question is this. In case I decide to keep ASPNETDB.MDF separate from the application DB, **how can I query 2 tables located in 2 different databases?**

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Would your queries need to access both databases at once? e.g. To Join a table in one database on a table in another?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have two databases/schemas on the same database server, you can query across databases with the following syntax:

```
select *
from database1.dbo.table1 t1 join database2.dbo.table2 t2 on
  t1.field1 = t2.field2
```

If they are on physically separate servers, you can still do a cross-database query, but you need to link the servers first:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: In addition to using 3 part object name syntax you would also have to either set up the server to allow [cross database ownership chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx) or mark the DB [as trusworthy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2183687). Both have security implications.

Comment: To make things easier for now, let's say (i) I created a DB under the App_Data and (ii) ASPNETDB.MDF is generated for me when I access the membership module for the first time. Is that you mean by "same database server"?

Comment: He means the data is stored onthe same physical server, that has nothing to do with how it wsa created but with where it was created.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your SQL Server version by:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')
```

---

If you are using "**SQL Azure**" you will not be able to use a table from different database. You will get this error:

***Reference to database and/or server name in 'DataBase.Schema.Table' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.***

Even if you try to Query a different database from your file like this:

```
USE ANOTHER_DATABASE;
```

You will get this error:

***USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.***